# How do I index a dictionary that i have turned into a list

Tags: python

Basically i have turned a dictionary into a list. Now i want to get the first,second,third, and fourth value of the list by indexing. I do not know where i have made a mistake but it does not let me index.

I have tried

```
newcouples3 = remaining1.keys()
newcouple3 = newcouples3[2]
```

but then I get an error.

```
{'Couple3': 9, 'Couple4': 12, 'Couple5': 15, 'Couple6': 18}   

newcouples3 = remaining1.keys()
newcouple3 = newcouples3[2]
```

I want to get the first,second,third, and fourth key in that list.

i get this error:

```
newcouple3 = newcouples3[2]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: your code is mal-indented. Could you use '4 space' before each line so we can understand it? besides, show the original code also.

Comment: Neither `.keys` nor `.items` returns a list, you have to use `list` as well

Answer (score 3):

That's because indexing works on `list` type and `.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object which doesn't support indexing.

You could do the following:

```
>>> some_dict = {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
>>> type(some_dict.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
>>> list(some_dict.keys())[0]
'a'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `dict.keys()` [returns a view object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict.keys).  You would need to turn it into a list first.

`newcouples3 = list(remaining1.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
myDict = {'Couple3': 9, 'Couple4': 12, 'Couple5': 15, 'Couple6': 18}
print(myDict)

myDictKeys = [ k for k in myDict ]
print(myDictKeys)
print(myDictKeys[1])

myDictValues = [ v for v in myDict.values() ]
print(myDictValues)
print(myDictValues[1])
```

Output:

```
{'Couple3': 9, 'Couple4': 12, 'Couple5': 15, 'Couple6': 18}
['Couple3', 'Couple4', 'Couple5', 'Couple6']
Couple4
[9, 12, 15, 18]
12
```